# DateTime in ApplicationData.LocalSettings

Tags: c#, uwp

From this blog post, it seems I should be able to store a `DateTime` as a `ApplicationData.LocalSettings` value, but I'm getting the exception below for this line.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastTokenRefresh"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/#bgpwEqDbEt0GClHB.97

Exception:

> Data of this type is not supported.
>
> Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store

What am I missing?

I'm currently converting the `DateTime` to string to make this work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a link redirection issue of that Blog which causes your misunderstanding of supported data type `DateTime`. You can refer to the official document: [Types of app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#types-of-app-data), the `DateTime` in this document will link you to [DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206576):

> JavaScript:  This type appears as the Date object.
>
> .NET:  When programming with .NET, this type is hidden, and developers should use the System.DateTimeOffset structure.
>
> C++:  Similar to FILETIME but with important differences.

It means, the supported type for date here is [System.DateTimeOffset Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), not [System.DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.datetime(v=vs.105).aspx). So, you can either modify your code like this:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastTokenRefresh"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```

Or you can keep using your `ToString()` method to save it, but when you retrieve this string type value, you may need to rebuild the string for using it in your code.